# How to insert value into a SQLite3 database in Python?

Tags: python, sqlite

I have the following function which inserts two values into my database, however, no matter how many times I try, the data is just not inserted. newname and newgrade are also successfully fetched in this function, just not passed to the database.

```
def addtolist():
    with sqlite3.connect("TestScore.db") as db:
            cursor = db.cursor()
    newname = sname.get()
    newgrade = sgrade.get()
    cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO Scores(name,score) VALUES (?,?)""", (newname, newgrade))
    db.commit
    sname.delete(0, END)
    sgrade.delete(0, END)
    sname.focus()
```

And I created the database like following

```
cursor.execute(""" CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Scores (id integer PRIMARY KEY, name text, score integer); """)
```

Comment: Isn't all that stuff supposed to be done *inside* the with-block?

Comment: Yes, and also, you *aren't actually calling `.commit`*

Comment: The problem here is the cursor exists between the with indentation. You could push everything inside the with block, or maintain an initial connection and finally close with `.close()` function.

Comment: Thank you so much! I didn't know that they need to be indented, can you please just explain why they need to be indented?

Answer (score 1):

You need to indent all your code to be inside the `with` block, and call the `commit()` function with parenthesis. Also, you should probably close the cursor once you're done inserting values.

Try the code below to see if it works:

```
def addtolist():
    with sqlite3.connect("TestScore.db") as db:
            cursor = db.cursor()
        newname = sname.get()
        newgrade = sgrade.get()
        cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO Scores(name,score) VALUES (?,?)""", (newname, newgrade))
        db.commit()
        sname.delete(0, END)
        sgrade.delete(0, END)
        sname.focus()
        cursor.close()
```